# Call onCreate and onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

In my application,

`activity` A calls `activity` B with explicit intent asking for result.

B takes a while, and A may be destroyed in the meantime.

In fact, B itself or even the whole application may be destroyed if you navigate away from B (home screen, another task...) and be recreated when navigating back to my app's task.

The problem now is: when B finally finishes its work and returns the result, what happens?

I would like A recreated and both, `onCreate()` and `onActivityResult`, called. But I have some suspicions as this is now a different instance of activity A. Reading other questions and answers, I noticed that some calls will happen in different instances of the same activity and memory leaks will happen etc. I want both methods called in the newly created instance of A (and the destroyed instance wiped out).

Is what I want what actually happens? If not, what happens and how should I go about it? All three scenarios matter: just A is destroyed, A and B are destroyed; the application is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

If Activity A gets destroyed by the time B finishes, the following will happen

1. A will be re-created.
2. B will deliver the result.

This is why results must be returned through a single Activity callback with an integer request code.

I suggest that you read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/x72BabVtWcQ).

Comment: `A` will be recreated. If you need to keep some state in `A` (for example, that you already launched B and are waiting for a result), then you need to save and restore this state in `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.